# passing string values inside a Regex

Tags: jquery, regex

Here is the code for controlling length of a numeric field before and after the decimal point...
Its working perfect. 
Is it possible to pass values instead of {0,4}, {0,2} as a string data.

```
$("#amount").on("keyup", function(){
    var valid = /^\d{0,4}(\.\d{0,2})?$/.test(this.value),
        val = this.value;

    if(!valid){
        console.log("Invalid input!");
        this.value = val.substring(0, val.length - 1);
    }
});
```

Comment: Am also Searching for this answer

Comment: @Tushar can u make it possible in this js fiddle ?? https://jsfiddle.net/p0f01ey4/

Comment: @ShanuShaji [`var range = "{0,4}"; var regex = new RegExp("^\\d" + range + "(\\.\\d{0,2})?$")`](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/p0f01ey4/1/)